# Recommended workflows for Apache virtual hosts?

Tags: apache2, webserver, virtualhost

I do a lot of local web development work on my Ubuntu machine, and I'm constantly setting up virtual hosts in Apache. I don't need to do hard core server management, but I am getting tired of the repetitive process of manually adding config directives to files in /etc/apache2/sites-available/ and then updating the /etc/hosts file.

Is there a more efficient or more automated way to do all this that I'm missing? Maybe something like [rapache](https://launchpad.net/rapache) but that's actually working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When I had to do shuch things I proceed creating a VirtualHost whit a wildcard name:

1. Choose a fancy domain name like 'example.com' for localhost
2. Place it in `/etc/hosts` file as `127.0.0.1 *.example.com`
3. Install and activate `mod_rewrite`
4. create a wildcard VirtualHost in apache sites directory:

   ```
   <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
     DocumentRoot /default/path
     ServerName example.com
     ServerAlias *.example.com
     RewriteEngine On
     UseCanonicalName Off

     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).example.com
     RewriteCond /srv/%1/ -d
     RewriteRule ^(.+)   %{SERVER_NAME}$1 [C]
     RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.example\.com/(.*) /srv/$1/$2 [L]
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
5. Now you can place any folder under `/srv/` and it will be the root for `<foldername>.example.com`

This is borrowed from memory, it could need some more minor adjustments and it may conflict with any other rewrite rules each webapp would have. But it fits me for my webapp testing needs.

Comment: That's very clever, will give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: Great answer. Except the wildcard didn't work for me, I had to [use dnsmasq](http://serverfault.com/a/118589) for get it to work.

Answer (score 3):

would [webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) work ? It's not just for apache but rather a web interface to system administration. It does have a form filling interface to apache virtual host.

Comment: Looked into webmin but thought it might be overkill, you know?

Comment: I use it on my development server, it makes things a bit easier though I still SSH in from time to time

Answer (score 0):

why not make a website that makes/updates the files for you? if you are working with php and this is local only use the exec() function to run terminal commands to write/create/update data that you want based on textbox entries. I wish i knew how to make applications on ubuntu that are gui based. would make life really easy.